# How do I style <v-slider disabled> to be like my enabled slider?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make it so my disabled `<v-slider>` looks identical to my enabled one:

[Here's an example of the enabled slider](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/YzGVaEJ)

```
<style>
.theme--light.v-slider .v-slider__track-background, .theme--light.v-slider .v-slider__track-fill, .theme--light.v-slider .v-slider__thumb {
    /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); */
    background: rgb(238, 238, 238);
}
.v-slider__track-fill {
    background: #2196f3!important;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that my range slider thumb appears to be white, or there is some sort of gap that I can't find in the css:

[image]

Is there an easy way to make disabled range slider styles match normal styles? Or a way to fix the thumb so it's blue too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<slider disabled>` use `<slider readonly>`. That way it won't add the disabled styles and allow you to maintain the normal styles with out the sliding functionality.

Answer (score 1):

i cant reproduce this in the codepen but can u try to add this style to your disabled slider..

if ur using scss/sass but scoped

```css
::v-deep .v-slider__track-fill {
  border-color: #2196f3 !important;
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}
```

if ur using css but scoped

```css
>>> .v-slider__track-fill {
  border-color: #2196f3 !important;
  background-color: #2196f3 !important;
}
```